# Dynamically created XML file not valid until opened in Dreamweaver

Tags: xml

I know that little things like whitespace at the beginning of the ror.xml file will throw errors, but how could opening the file in Dreamweaver, NOT CHANGING ANYTHING, and then uploading the file make it valid?

**Edit:** I don't think it makes a difference but the language of script is PHP. The script does the following:

1. file opens
2. gets compared
3. replaces content of file
4. closes the file

Looks great but does not work.

When I open both a generated ror.xml (which throws errors), and one I've re-saved (that works correctly), they both look in every way identical. It's Madness!

Comment: When you say it "throws errors", could you tell us which errors it's throwing? Also, if it's an RSS feed, what does the [W3 Feed Validator](http://validator.w3.org/feed/) say is wrong with it?

Comment: In the original question, the title references a certain rss.xml, but in the body itself, ror.xml appears. Can @Natrix please clarify if your XML file is a RSS feed?

Comment: Its an ror.xml file. error says     XML Parsing Error: not well-formed
Location: http://www.thewebsite.com/ror.xml
Line Number 1, Column 1:

Comment: Please tell us what error messages you're seeing, and what process is throwing the errors ("When I open" -- in what program?)

Comment: oXygen reports the file at the location you gave as being fine and well-formed. Is that the good version or the bad version?

Comment: I just tested http://www.creditrepairadvisors.net/ror.xml with the w3c and it highlighted line one. <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> - If I open the file in dreamweaver and save it, then upload it, without making any changes, it will validate. Why? And I'm simply clicking the rss button in firefox toolbar to test. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Natrix,

It looks like the source of the problem is one of two things. Either

- the program that's throwing the error (Firefox RSS button?) is mistaken about the XML not being well-formed; or
- DreamWeaver is actually fixing something.

The latter seems more likely. Can you show us a sample of the generated XML and the XML after Dreamweaver has opened it? I understand that they look identical. It's possible that the generated file has some characters that are incompatible with the declared encoding at the top of the file, and DreamWeaver is silently fixing those characters.

Ah... your sample at http://www.creditrepairadvisors.net/ror.xml **actually starts with a bunch of blank spaces** before the XML prologue. (Well, it did the first time I accessed it.) That's not allowed in an XML document. Make it start with `<?xml ...?>` immediately. That's probably what Dreamweaver is fixing.

Note, you used the word 'valid' in your question, but this is not an issue of XML validity (conformity to a schema of some sort). It's saying the XML is not well-formed. And if it's not well-formed, then it can't even be tested for validity.

Comment: Awesome thanks. I figured dw was fixing something i couldn't see. I have a little direction where to start resolving the issue in the script. I'm hoping a quick str_replace(" ","",$crud) will remedy the pain. Thanks again.